# Test if a list is a permutation of another list

Tags: permutation

This question may have a simple answer, but I can't find it anywhere in the documentation. I'm trying to find a function that tells me whether a list is a permutation of another list. So the function should behave like this:

```
TestPermutation[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 3, 2, 4}] (* Should return True *)

TestPermutation[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 1, 2, 4}] (* Should return False *)
```

What sort of works is to use `FindPermutation[list1, list2]`, and then catch the error that says e.g.:

```
FindPermutation::norel: Expressions {1,2,3} and {2,1,2} cannot be related by a permutation. >>
```

But that isn't a very nice solution. Is there a neat way do do this?

Comment: Sort[list1]==Sort[list2]

Comment: @george2079 - pity, that you didn't post your comment as an answer - too trivial?

Comment: i think   you can  test if the Complement of the first list with the second one is 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

so this doesn't sit unanswered..

```
 testPermutation[ list1_List , list2_List ] := Sort[list1] == Sort[list2] ; 
 testPermutation[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 3, 2, 4}]
 testPermutation[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 1, 2, 4}]
```

> True
>
> False

or generalized to multiple lists:

```
 testPermutation[ list__List  ] := Equal @@ Sort /@ List@list
 testPermutation[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 3, 2, 4}, {1, 2, 4, 3}]
 testPermutation @@ Permutations[{1, 2, 3, 4}]
```

> True
>
> True

Comment: `SameQ` or `MatchQ` may be preferable to `Equal`.

Answer (score 2):

Not so nice as george2079's answer but maybe faster with large matrices (avoids sorting):

```
testPermutation[m_] := 
 Length@Flatten@
      Table[Position[m[[i]], m[[1, j]]], {i, 2, Length@m}, {j, 1, 
        Length@First@m}] == (Times @@ # - Last@#&@Dimensions@m)

testPermutation@{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 3, 2, 4}, {1, 2, 4, 3}}
```

> True

```
testPermutation@{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 3, 2, 4}, {5, 2, 4, 3}}
```

> False

Answer (score 1):

Another simple solution could be based on Cycles[]. The existence of duplicates is also tested.

```
testPermutation[l1_List, l2_List] :=
 With[{
   len1 = Length@l1,
   lu1 = CountDistinct@l1,
   lu2 = CountDistinct@l2}, 
  And[lu1 == lu2 == len1, Cycles[{l1}] == Cycles[{l2}]]]
```